# What does the sequence, s = $\dfrac{1}{n}$ converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I got this problem on my homework asking if the sequence a = $\dfrac{1}{n^2} + \dfrac{2}{n^2} + \dfrac{3}{n^2} + ... +\dfrac{n}{n^2}$, which I think is the same as asking what the sequence s = $\dfrac{1}{n}$ converges to. I am pretty confused as I thought the series of $\dfrac{1}{n}$ diverges? Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: The _series_ $\Sigma\dfrac1n$ diverges; what is $1+2+3+\cdots+n$?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373357/what-is-an-intuitive-approach-to-solving-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-biggl-frac) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164457/evaluate-limit-of-the-series-lim-n-to-infty-left-frac1n2-frac2) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637412/would-this-solution-of-the-limit-of-the-sequence-be-correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the sum stops at $\frac n{n^2}$, which allows a finite value to be assigned to it.

For a fixed $n$ we can sum the terms and get $\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}=\frac12\cdot\frac{n+1}n$, whose limit as $n\to\infty$ is $\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is a difference between series and sequence. These two words are confusing and interchangeable in nonmathematical language. But in mathematics, series is sequence obtained from a given sequence.

**Series 1/n diverges but the sequence 1/n converges.**